# File permission on Amazon EC2 with both Filezilla and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2

1. I can allow user ec2-user (Amazon AWS) write access to the public
   web directory (/var/www/html):

   ```
   sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
   ```

   *which allows me to use Filezilla.*
2. And I can allow apache write access by:

   ```
   sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
   ```

   *which allows me to install plugins, updates, etc on Wordpress.*

How can I set the permissions to be able to do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Create a group
2. Add both users to that group
3. Make the group own the directory
4. Change the directory group permissions

---

```
sudo groupadd mygroup

sudo gpasswd -a apache mygroup
sudo gpasswd -a ec2-user mygroup

sudo chown -R apache:mygroup /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```